# download files in R while maintaining original structure

Tags: r, download

The code example below is to download census data by state from the census.gov website. The problem I run into is that the leading zeros are deleted when I download as a csv file. How do I maintain the original structure of the files while downloading?

```
  stateFIPScodes<-seq(10,13,1)

  for(i in 1:length(stateFIPScodes)){
      URL<-paste("https://www.census.gov/popest/data/intercensal/county/files/CO-EST00INT-  ALLDATA-",stateFIPScodes[i],".csv",sep="" )
      destfile<-paste("state2000_2010_",stateFIPScodes[i],".csv" ,sep="") # CSV files drop leading zero!!
      download.file(URL, destfile)
 }
```

Thank you!

Comment: Are you viewing the data with Excel or a text editor? Excel has a tendency to remove the zeros by treating values as numbers instead of strings. If you open the file with a plain text editor and the zeros are there, it indicates that your code is fine and you'll just have to trick Excel.

Comment: @JorganPubshire Thanks. I converted the files to download as text document instead of Excel and that appears to maintain the original structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears as if the files are *downloaded* correctly, but you are correct: if you use `read.csv` to load the data into R, then some of the columns are interpreted as `numeric`, and therefore they lose the leading zeros.

To take your code that downloads files -

```
stateFIPScodes<-seq(10,13,1)

for(i in seq_along(stateFIPScodes)){
  code <- stateFIPScodes[[i]]
  URL <- paste0("https://www.census.gov/popest/data/intercensal/county/files/CO-EST00INT-ALLDATA-", code, ".csv")
  destfile <- paste0("state2000_2010_",code,".csv") 
  download.file(URL, destfile)
}
```

If we use base `read.csv` we get no trailing zeros:

```
library(dplyr)

read.csv("state2000_2010_10.csv") %>%
  select(1:5) %>%
  head

#>   SUMLEV STATE COUNTY   STNAME     CTYNAME
#> 1     50    10      1 Delaware Kent County
#> 2     50    10      1 Delaware Kent County
#> 3     50    10      1 Delaware Kent County
#> 4     50    10      1 Delaware Kent County
#> 5     50    10      1 Delaware Kent County
#> 6     50    10      1 Delaware Kent County
```

That's because the first few columns are being read in as numeric.

```
read.csv("state2000_2010_10.csv") %>% str()
#> 'data.frame':    780 obs. of  50 variables:
#>  $ SUMLEV      : int  50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 ...
#>  $ STATE       : int  10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 ...
#>  $ COUNTY      : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
```

There are two ways to resolve this:

1. Manually pass the data types into `read.csv`, or just prevent all conversions by adding `colClasses = "character"`.
2. Use `readr::read_csv` which handles it correctly.

We could just prevent automatic coercion:

```
read.csv("state2000_2010_10.csv", colClasses = "character") %>% str()
#> 'data.frame':    780 obs. of  50 variables:
#>  $ SUMLEV      : chr  "050" "050" "050" "050" ...
#>  $ STATE       : chr  "10" "10" "10" "10" ...
#>  $ COUNTY      : chr  "001" "001" "001" "001" ...
#>  $ STNAME      : chr  "Delaware" "Delaware" "Delaware" "Delaware" ...
```

You would need to choose what columns you wanted to cast to `as.numeric`.

Or you could select the columns, e.g.

```
read.csv("state2000_2010_10.csv", 
         colClasses = c(
           SUMLEV = "character",
           STATE = "numeric",
           COUNTY = "character"
         )) %>%
  select(1:5) %>%
  head

#>   SUMLEV STATE COUNTY   STNAME     CTYNAME
#> 1    050    10    001 Delaware Kent County
#> 2    050    10    001 Delaware Kent County
#> 3    050    10    001 Delaware Kent County
#> 4    050    10    001 Delaware Kent County
#> 5    050    10    001 Delaware Kent County
#> 6    050    10    001 Delaware Kent County
```

Second, you could use `readr`, which has more intelligent column type inference:

```
#> read_csv("state2000_2010_10.csv") %>%
#>    select(1:5) %>%
#>    head
#> # A tibble: 6 × 5
#>   SUMLEV STATE COUNTY   STNAME     CTYNAME
#>    <chr> <int>  <chr>    <chr>       <chr>
#> 1    050    10    001 Delaware Kent County
#> 2    050    10    001 Delaware Kent County
#> 3    050    10    001 Delaware Kent County
#> 4    050    10    001 Delaware Kent County
#> 5    050    10    001 Delaware Kent County
#> 6    050    10    001 Delaware Kent County
```

Comment: Seems overly complex for an answer that could have just been ...use: `colClasses="character", stringsAsFactors=FALSE`.